# Don't use OFFSET they say but what's the actual purpose of OFFSET?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pagination

It appears that `OFFSET` is not recommended when dealing with large records because of slow performance and instead just use something like `WHERE id < x LIMIT y`.

If this is the case why does OFFSET exists, is there another use for it?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, the way that `offset` (and `limit` for that matter) works is that the entire result set is filtered after it is generated. So, in order to get the the "y"th row, all the rows up that one need to be generated.

If there is another method to get the same rows using `where`, then that will normally be faster (for large values of "y"), because the intermediate rows don't have to be generated.

However, `offset` is still very useful. How else would you easily get the candidates who are 11+ in average poll ratings from candidates, so you know who to put in the "also-ran" debate? How would you get the second highest value, fi that is what you want? For smaller datasets, `offset` can be very useful for these types of questions. It is also useful for paging on smaller result sets.

Comment: MySql applies limit while the resultset is generated, not after, thus speeding up the query.

Comment: @Shadow Can you provide a reference source please?